# Problem with Logging Module in Google Colab

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a python script with an error handling using the logging module. Although this python script works when imported to google colab, it doesn't log the errors in the log file.

As an experiment, I tried this following script in google colab just to see if it writes log at all

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="log_file_test.log",
                            filemode='a',
                            format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                            datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                            level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info("This is a test log ..")
```

To my dismay, it **didn't even create** a log file named **log_file_test.log**. I tried running the same script **locally** and it **did produce** a file **log_file_test.log** with the following text

> 13:20:53,441 root INFO This is a test log ..

What is it that I am missing here?
For the time being, I am replacing the error logs with print statements, but I assume that there must be a workaround to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you've reconfigured your environment somehow? (Try Runtime menu -> Reset all runtimes...) Your snippets works exactly as written for me --

[image]

Answer (score 11):

`logging.basicConfig` can be run just once*

Any subsequent call to `basicConfig` is ignored.

`*` unless you are in Python 3.8 and use the flag [force=True](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.basicConfig)

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    force=True, # Resets any previous configuration
                    )
```

---

*Workarounds (2)*

`(1)` You can easily reset the Colab workspace with this command

```
exit
```

Wait for it to come back and try your commands again.

`(2)` But, if you plan to do the reset more than once and/or are learning to use `logging`, maybe it is better to use [`%%python` magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-python3) to run the entire cell in a subprocess. See photo below.

[image]

---

> What is it that I am missing here?

Deeper understanding of how `logging` works. It is a bit tricky, but there are many good webs explaining the gotchas.

- [In Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/aviadr1/learn-advanced-python/blob/master/content/15_logging/logging_in_python.ipynb#scrollTo=Ggq2S1rLpJLp)
- https://realpython.com/python-logging

Comment: For me logging.basicConfig(force=True) worked. Is it possible that notebook (and colab) run logging.basicConfig() at startup? In this case further logging.basicConfig() commands are ignored unless force=True is set.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer][1] cover the issue.
You have to:

1. Clear your log handlers from the environment with logging.root.removeHandler
2. Set log level with logging.getLogger('RootLogger').setLevel(logging.DEBUG).

Setting level with logging.basicConfig only did not work for me.

Comment: Your link is missing the url