# Python Logging module not working in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, python-logging

I will start by saying the I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597462/problem-with-logging-module-in-google-colab) and none of the suggested solutions worked for me at the end of 2022.

I do not manage to do simple things like changing the severity level of the logging on Colab:

[image]

Or writing the logs to a file:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', force=True)
logging.warning('This will get logged to a file')
```

As Colab is very popular and so it is the logging module, I thought it makes sense to ask again.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, the debug message does not print because the lowest severity of the root logger is set to `WARNING`. You can change it to `DEBUG` with

```
import logging

logging.getLogger('RootLogger').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

---

For the second problem, as Colab is still on Python 3.7 and not 3.8, the `force=` parameter does not work yet. So you just need to manually delete the default `StreamHandler` that sends logging output to `sys.stderr` before carrying out your configuration. (code source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49202811/9987623)

```
import logging

# Check current handlers
print(logging.root.handlers)
# [<StreamHandler stderr (NOTSET)>]

# Remove all handlers associated with the root logger object.
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
print(logging.root.handlers)
# []
```

Now, you can run your code. Here is an example:

```
from pathlib import Path

fmt = '%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
log_dir = Path.cwd().joinpath("logs")
path = Path(log_dir)
path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
log_fname = "app.log"
log_path = log_dir.joinpath(log_fname)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filemode="w",
    format=fmt,
    filename=log_path,
)
logging.warning("this is a warning")
```

Next cell:

```
!cat ./logs/app.log
# root - WARNING - this is a warning
```

Next cell:

```
logging.debug('this is a debug message')
```

Next cell:

```
!cat ./logs/app.log
# root - WARNING - this is a warning
# root - DEBUG - this is a debug message
```